# no connection with SQL Server

Tags: laravel

I have an issue with connect my laravel project with SQL Server.
I am usine Windows Server 2019 with SQL Server 2022
once i need to migrate database sohw me this error:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the targ
et machine actively refused it.
 (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: select * from sys.sysobjects where id = object_id(migrations) and xtype in ('U', 'V'))

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:795
    791▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    792▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    793▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    794▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 795▕             throw new QueryException(
    796▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    797▕             );
    798▕         }
    799▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be m
ade because the target machine actively refused it.
")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDO::__construct()
```

is there any one can fix my issue?

all this configration is enabled:
[protocols for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmAKu.png)